# Cake php and using auth in layout

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using auth component and it works ok.
But in my default layout before the content I have some menu which is different if user is logged in. So I want to determine if user is logged in or not - normally I use $this->Auth->user('id') but $this->Auth doesnt work in layout (it only works in view which controller is using Auth component).

How to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read Auth data from session. Something like:

```
$user = $session->read('Auth');
```

Don`t forget to add Session helper in your AppController.

```
var $helpers = array('Session');
```

Comment: This is just a less DRY solution than the one I provided. You'll have to call everywhere where you need it $this->Session->read() plus loading the helper when not always needed.

Comment: I think the main reason why he asked about layout but not view was fact that he wanted to post it everywhere.

Comment: Layout is the same as view... Whatever is set to the View (Class) is available in the layout too.

Answer (score 12):

In beforeRender() just call

```
$this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
```

and set the data to the view and do your checks in the view.

In order to get data in layout, you should call `beforeRender()` method in AppController.

Passing it through session is not a good idea IMHO. It might be not the usual case but at least I prefer to do things solid: If you're using the session for that your code will fail in a system that is not using a session (stateless auth). Overall I'm not a big fan of accessing the session in a view at all. Session is for me more like a datasource.

Comment: But I need it in the layout not in view! Layout doesnt have any controller where I can put beforeRender...

Comment: You obviously do not know how CakePHP or MVC works? This will set the data to the view and by this make it available in all layouts. A layout is actually just a part of a view. A layout is rendered the same way as a view, a view is just rendered inside the layout. Also I suggest you to try code before telling somebody it's not working.